# write a simple benchmarking tool in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I want to write a simple benchmarking tool in java, that will spin up x threads and hit a url y times in total.

The actual task part of it will make a web request to a url, and post a XML file.

So what I want to do is, spin off 50 threads and keep hitting the url until I have made 10K requests.

Can someone explain how to do this, I believe using the Executor Service is the way to go.

Some things to consider:

1. Once a thread is finished, I'm guessing it will immediately run another task correct?
2. I need the thread to return as I have to keep track of success/failures, where should this be stored (it has to be thread-safe).

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean "load simulator"? Benchmarking usually involves some issue of speed, where this sounds kind of like "hit my 10k times, and see how many requests fail". I ask because if you want a benchmark, and not a stress test, the results would be different.

Comment: @jtahlborn I have the actual task to run i.e. post xml file to my url.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `ExecutorService` is a perfect choice for this task:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
```

Start measuring time and simply submit 10K tasks to it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
  exec(new SubmitToUrlTask());
}
```

Consider using the same instance of (stateless or thread-safe) `SubmitToUrlTask` rather than creating new one in each iteration.

At the end you must wait for the executor to finish:

```
exec.shutdown();
if(!exec.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTE)) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Waiting for too long, captain!");
}
```

Stop measuring the time now. `awaitTermination()` blocks until **all** tasks have finished, but not longer than given time (1 mminute in the example).

> Once a thread is finished, I'm guessing it will immediately run another task correct?

Yes, `ExecutorService` is a bunch of threads and a queue of tasks. If a thread does not have anything to do, it takes first task from the queue.

> I need the thread to return as I have to keep track of success/failures, where should this be stored (it has to be thread-safe).

You can use `Callable<Boolean>` and `Future<Boolean>` to track results. Also if you are using only a single instance of `SubmitToUrlTask`, it can have two variables of `AtomicInteger` type, tracking both successes and failures. This is much simpler if you don't need to track individual results.

That being said, have you considered using [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) that has all these functionalities + much more out of the box? There is also [`ab`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) console utility.

Comment: @codecompleting: Yes, I actually added this to my answer while you posted your question. See my update.

Comment: Yes I know of jmeter, I want to learn this also, but also write my own custom tool.

Comment: actually I was reading that jmeter loads the file on each request, so it is really slow if the file is large.  a custom solution it's easy to understand what it is actually doing for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the annotated source code which outlines a strategy you can use:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class LoadGen {
    /**
     * Hits the given url for nRequests times on nUsers threads.
     *
     * @return LoadGen.Result object with status of the test
     */
    public static Result generateLoad(final String url,
        int nUsers, int nRequests) throws InterruptedException {
        // A thread pool with one thread per simulated user
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nUsers);

        // A latch awaited on by the user threads before the test is started
        final CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // A latch awaited on by the main thread for all user threads 
        // to complete the test
        final CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(nUsers);

        // The Result object for this test run
        final Result result = new Result(nRequests);

        // Submit one Runnable per simulated user
        for (int i = 0; i < nUsers; i++) {
            threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // the Runnable awaits for the test to start
                        startSignal.await();

                        runSimulatedUser(url, result);

                        // indicate that this thread has completed
                        doneSignal.countDown();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Start all simulated user threads
        startSignal.countDown();

        // Wait for all simulated user threads to complete the test
        doneSignal.await();

        // Dispose all threads
        threadPool.shutdownNow();
        return result;
    }

    private static void runSimulatedUser(String url, Result result) {
        // run repeatedly ..
        while (true) {
            try {
                // hitting the URL, marking success and failure
                // until nRequests requests are made in total
                makeRequest(url);
                if (! result.success()) {
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (! result.failure()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void makeRequest(String url) {
        // TODO: post the XML document to the URL etc
        System.out.println("Making request");
    }

    public static class Result {
        private final AtomicInteger nSuccess = new AtomicInteger();
        private final AtomicInteger nFailure = new AtomicInteger();
        private final AtomicInteger nTotal;

        public Result(int nTotal) {
            this.nTotal = new AtomicInteger(nTotal);
        }

        boolean success() {
            nSuccess.incrementAndGet();
            return nTotal.decrementAndGet() > 1;
        }

        boolean failure() {
            nFailure.incrementAndGet();
            return nTotal.decrementAndGet() > 1;
        }

        int getSuccessCount() {
            return nSuccess.get();
        }

        int getFailureCount() {
            return nFailure.get();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // generate 10 requests on 2 threads
        LoadGen.generateLoad("http://myurl.com", 2, 10);
    }
}
```